# Потеря данных на многопоточном парсинге. Python

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

Есть веб-сайт, который работает на связке nginx->uwsgi->django. Со стороны сервера, по запросу пользователя, идёт скрапинг одного сайта в несколько потоков. Когда заканчиваются данные на сайте, выбрасывается исключение и поток закрывается. Если на сервер поступает реквест от одного пользователя, то все в порядке. Но если их хотя бы >5, то часть данных теряется. То есть в одном случае, например 700 позиций, а в другом 200. Есть подозрение, что проблема в потоках. Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Класс потока выглядит так -

```
class parserThread(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, counter, url, qurl):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.threadID = counter
    self.counter = counter
    self.url = url
    self.qurl = qurl

def run(self):
    if self.counter == 1:
        for i in range(2, self.counter * 10 + 1):
                res = scratch('%s/page%s%s' % (self.url,i,self.qurl))
                threadLock.acquire()
                parse(res)
                threadLock.release()
        return

    else:
        for i in range(self.counter*10-4,self.counter * 10 + 1):
                res = scratch('%s/page%s%s' % (self.url,i,self.qurl))
                threadLock.acquire()
                parse(res)
                threadLock.release()
        return
```

Запуск потоков -

```
for i in range(10):
    thread = parserThread(i+1, url, qurl)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Опять же замечу, что если сервер получает один реквест, то он его корректно обрабатывает. Проблема, скорее всего, во взаимодействии потоков между функциями-обработчиками от разных реквестов при появлении exception, который извещает, что данные для парсинга закончились.

Comment: Вижу два возможных варианта проблемы: 1) например, дело не в факте использования потоков, а в не умении с ними работать, т.е. где-то проблема с кодом. 2) или проблема с сайтами, которые парсите, может быть, что когда к ним приходят много запроса от вашей парсилки, те в защиту от ботов / ддос атаки показывают какую заглушку, типо ввода капчи, а парсер не научили такое определять и поэтому тот не смог вытащить данные и вы получили меньше чем при меньшей нагрузке

Comment: С заглушкой проблем не наблюдал, часть информации все равно корректная. И если там, допустим, сто страниц выдачи, то с каждой страницы будет информация. Плюс число результатов разное выдает. Где-то 400, где-то 200, где-то 700. Может быть такое, что при эксепшене поток с одного реквеста закрывает поток с другого реквеста?

Comment: `Может быть такое, что при эксепшене поток с одного реквеста закрывает поток с другого реквеста?` это внутренняя кухня вашего сервера и тут может быть что угодно :)

Comment: Ради интереса, какие библиотеки используете для парсинга, и  используете ли библиотеки для создания пула потоков?

Comment: Django разработан не просто непотокобезопасным, а даже принудительно однозадачным. Любые попытки использовать потоки или асинхронность в django-коде - это путь боли и страдания. Используйте Celery или uWSGI Pools.

Comment: Использую threading. Для создания пулов ничего не использую

Comment: upd: Добавил к вопросу код и некоторые разъяснения. Если не появится лучшего ответа, то попрошу @SergeyGornostaev ответить, чтобы можно было отметить, как ответ.

Comment: @danilshik Для парсинга использую beautifulsoup4